# Can not edit comment form

Tags: comment-form

I'm trying to add author, email fields to comment form but the comment form does not change. It is always showing a default template with only the comment field and submit button.

Could this be a caching issue or it is reading the comment form template from another directory?

I am using this code in my page template :

```
$comments_args = array(
  'label_submit' => __('コメント送信'),
  'title_reply' => __('コメント登録'),
  'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', array(
    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author">'.
    '<input id="author" class="blog-form-input" placeholder="Your Name* " name="author" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']).
    '" size="30"'.$aria_req.
    ' /></p>',
    'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email">'.
    '<input id="email" class="blog-form-input" placeholder="Your Email Address* " name="email" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']).
    '" size="30"'.$aria_req.
    ' /></p>',
  )),
  'comment_notes_after' => '',
  'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'._x('Comment', 'noun').
  '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" cols="75"></textarea></p>',
);
comment_form($comments_args);
```

Comment: why are you using apply_filters? you should add a filter

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in your current theme function.php file [More Info](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/)

```
<?php

    add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'additional_fields' );
    add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );
    
    function additional_fields () {
      echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
      '<label for="title">' . __( 'Comment Title' ) . '</label>'.
      '<input id="title" name="title" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';
    }
?>
```

> EDIT:

```
$comments_args = array(
       'comment_notes_after' => '<p><label for="comment">' . _x( 'NEW', 'noun' ) .
    '</label><input id="new" name="new" aria-required="true">' .
    '</input></p>',
    );

    comment_form($comments_args);
```

[Check more Argument list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

[image]

Comment: Can i edit comment form from my template page using comment_form($custom_fields);  instead of inserting them directly into functions.php  ?

Comment: Using it as comment_form($comments_args); does not work. I still see the comment form with comment field and submit button

Comment: custom filed add into this 'comment_notes_after'.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: please check my screen shot it's work for me

Comment: OK,clearing the browser cache made only 'NEW' field visible but name,email fields are still not in the form . Also , i checked my template files and could not find a comments.php file.. Could it be related to missing comments.php file ?